# prerequisite for installing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I need to install numpy for python 2.7.8 cersion. Every time i try installing using install setup.py command, a long list of files are shown as NOT AVAILABLE.

Please let me know if there are any prerequisites for installing numpy.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html#prerequisites

Comment: If you're running windows, why don't you just download and install win32 superpack version from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/